# Strange behavior in Kotlin

Tags: android

Consider the following code:

```
1     domesticUsage?.run {
2         items.add(DelimiterListItem())
3         items.add(SpacerListItem(resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.vertical_margin)))
4         if (title.isNotEmpty()) {
5             items.add(SubscriptionHeaderViewListItem(title, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL))
6         }
7         
8         usage1?.let { mainUsageDataList.add(it) }
9         usage2?.let { mainUsageDataList.add(it) }
10        if (mainUsageDataList.isNotEmpty()) {
11            items.add(SubscriptionUsageStatListItem(mainUsageDataList))
12        }
13        
14        extra?.run {
15            items.add(SideExtraBannerListItem(title, subtitle))
16        }
17    
18    } ?: items.add(ErrorReloadListItem(ErrorType.NO_DATA_MOBILE))
```

My problem is simple:
If `extra` (line 14) is null then I'm expecting this to be the last executed line in this snippet, but what happens when debugging is that it jumps back to line `1` and then to line `18` thus executing the `ErrorReload` view.

This shouldn't happen, right? The `ErrorReload` view should only we added if the `domesticUsage` in line `1` is null, right?

What am I missing here?

By the way, the editor shows this `^run` at the end of line `16`. What does that mean?
[image]

Comment: that's because `run` returns a value, in your case you implicitly return the result of `extra?.run`, which is null, triggering the  `?:` on the outer `run`

Comment: @TimCastelijns How can I fix it such that if `extra` is null the it jumps out of the `domesticUsage` run?

Comment: You may need to change your functions. This is run's signature: `inline fun <R> run(block: () -> R): R` so run is expecting to return the type of your block... make it return Unit perhaps? (I'm guessing here w/out seeing more code)

Comment: (the `^ run` is indicating that that's the block's closing bracket from the run method as far as I can remember reading somewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intention was to use `let` and `run` as a shorter way for verifying non-null operations, but it looks like nesting those in the way I did causes more harm then good, so I ended up going back to the good old `!= null` way:

```
domesticUsage?.run {
    items.add(DelimiterListItem())
    items.add(SpacerListItem(resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.vertical_margin)))

    if (title.isNotEmpty()) {
        items.add(SubscriptionHeaderViewListItem(title, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL))
    }

    if (usage1 != null)
        mainUsageDataList.add(usage1)

    if (usage2 != null)
        mainUsageDataList.add(usage2)

    if (mainUsageDataList.isNotEmpty()) {
        items.add(SubscriptionUsageStatListItem(mainUsageDataList))
    }

    if (extra != null)
        items.add(SideExtraBannerListItem(extra.title, extra.subtitle))

} ?: items.add(ErrorReloadListItem(ErrorType.NO_DATA_MOBILE))
```

If anyone cares to comment on a shorter approach which won't result in the error view being added accidentally, I'll be happy to see that.